# how to validate a checkbox in a repeater control using javascript

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, repeater

i have a repeater control in that a checkbox is added for a studies column.
i want to get the rows for checkbox selected...hw to do this??

i have checkbox in itemtemplate like this

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="GRAD_STUDIES_IND"  Value='<%#Container.DataItem("GRADSTUDIES")%>'
DataSetID="dsStudent" BoundDataMember="school"
Bind="false" RepeaterDataSource='<% # Container %>'  />
```

this control checkboxes 2 columns...but i want to access only one column
i tried this way

```
var rp1=document.getelemtbyID('<%=rp_student.ClientID%>')
var chk= rp1.getelementbytagname('input')
```

hw can i access particular column chekboxes

Comment: paste your repeater code and mark it as code so we can read it.

Comment: the repeater is inside a panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery. Since it makes the task easy for you. You can put the repeater in a well id-ed div element; also give a good class name for your checkbox and do something like:

```
$('#chkContainer .chks').each(function(){

    if(this.checked){
        //validation code goes here
    }
});
```

I've only shown you a simple way, the actual path to take is your own creation.

UPDATE:

Well, since you are not using jQuery, try something like:

```
var divContainer = document.getElementById('chkContainer');
var inputs = divContainer.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(x=0; x<inputs.length; x++){
    var element = inputs[x];
    //check if the element if of type checkbox,
    //and if that checkbox is checked
    if(element.type == 'checkbox' && element.checked){
        //code goes here...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks...we are not using jquery ...so can please tell using javascript

Comment: i tried thisway this is helpfull...but i have checkboxes in 2 columns, i want to check only for a single column with the above it checks all the checkboxes. how can i access for a particular column??

Comment: I feel all these can be separate questions. But anyway the following page should give you a hint: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Table/TablecellIndexExample.htm In your case `element.parentNode.cellIndex` should give a value; check if this corresponds to the 2nd column.